# Sci fi movie/TV episode where pin/bolt disappears back of people’s neck

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This was a sci-fi tv show/episode (or movie?) where people inserted a pin/bolt into the back of people’s neck & disappears and somehow either changed or gained info. But it’s different in the sense of Matrix where you sit in a seat & the insert is part of chair of where you’re sitting it doesn’t disappear completely in the neck as what I am trying to remember. It’s like you wouldn’t know it unless you knew they did it.

Time period being most likely 99s/2000s but could be as wide of time of coming out (1980s-2010 at most)

Comment: There was a *Doctor Who* episode almost like this (9th Doctor I believe, so right around that time period), only the jack was located in the person's forehead, not the back of the neck.  It was similarly concealed when not in use though.

Comment: Is it [Johnny Mnemonic (1995)](https://youtu.be/EFJY_BZ55sI)?

Comment: Getting vibes of Fringe later seasons here, as the Observers get their heightened abilities and extra environmental information through an implant at the back of the neck.

Comment: Reminds me of Existenz but the insert is biological and more like a vr game console

Comment: Fringe seems close. But for some reason seemed almost military type people maybe.

Answer (score 11):

This could be [Saturn 3](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079285/), released in 1980.

The pins inserted into the back of the neck were quite wide, and required a socket to be surgically installed.

Benson (Harvey Keitel) - a new arrival at a remote space station - claimed that the pins were only a means to control and communicate with a robot who arrived with him.

But later, he installs a socket in one of the space station's crew - Adam (Kirk Douglas) - without consent, and it's implied that the pins and sockets can also be used for mind controlling other humans.

Comment: A movie panned but I liked it. Certainly had some decent acting and interesting dialog.

Comment: No, but in that realm of technology feel going on though. Thanks

Comment: Thanks all you all been helping sorting out what from.